# underline part of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml

I'm building a table that displays the dates of the next 10 days. I need to insert the day, date, month and year into the table.  I'm using this JavaScript code for this:

```
document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = weekday + " " + date + " " + month + " " + year;
```

**My problem:**

I want to underline the month, but not the other values.
How can I fix this one? I already tried giving a CSS class along with the variable but I keep failing quite hard.

If more details or code is needed, please ask. This is my first time posting here and only javascripting for a month or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do want to use a CSS class to give meaning to that portion of the element and style it.  Wrap it in a `<span>` with the given class and then apply the styles through your style sheet.

```
document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = weekday + " " 
                                       + date
                                       + " <span class='month'>" + month + "</span> "
                                       + year;
```

Style

```
.month { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Using a semantic class, rather than a specific tag or inline styles, allows you to easily change the style of this type of display on a global basis rather than having to update each individual place where the styling occurs.

**EDIT:** Obviously you know your application best, but I would avoid underlining except for links or where convention  dictates (like some titles) that it should be used.  It can be very confusing for a user since underlining in a browser typically conveys that something is a clickable link.  That doesn't seem to be what you're going for here, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant solution, but just works:

```
document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = weekday + " " + date + " <span style='text-decoration: underline;'>" + month + "</span> " + year;
```

Comment: Inline styles? Really?  I suppose if it were a plugin with well-defined semantics, maybe, but I'd really go with a class-based approach even in that case if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just give it markup since innerHTML implies that you can put html there.

```
document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = weekday + " " + date + " <u>" + month + "</u>" + year;
```

I just used an underline tag :)

Comment: this is what I was trying to pull off and failed, now i see i put the tags in the wrong place. I tried it like: " " + <u> month </u>. thanks a lot :)

Comment: I believe that the `<u>` tag is deprecated, i.e., you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the HTML `<u>` tag. For example:

```
document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = weekday + " " + date + " <u>" + month + "</u> " + year;
```

Here's an example using the above method > http://jsfiddle.net/vuS4B/

But it might be better for you to do this using a `<span>` element, and add a CSS class to the span. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = weekday + " " + date + " <span class='underline'>" + month + "</span> " + year;
```

And the associated CSS:

```
span.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Here's the jsFiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/vuS4B/1/

Comment: I (obviously, see my answer) like using the class approach BUT it should be semantic, communicating what the element is, not what styling should be applied. If later you decide that month names should be italicized, you have to go back and change the class you're applying rather than simply changing the style of the class applied to month names.